# Random empty side scrolling space

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm new to HTML and CSS. For some reason my page has empty space on the right side and lets the user side scroll. I know I can hide the scroll bar with overflow-x but that still lets them scroll. How do I get rid of the extra space/why is it there? There's more of it on the index page than on the projects page.

zarwanhashem.com

Comment: Which part of your site? Why didn't I see the symptom you described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<div>` that contains the text 'Hello...' has a default width of 100% of the page. But you have set it's position to `relative` and pushed it `30em` to the left - which is pushing it off the right side of the page, causing the scroll.

There are lots of ways you could fix it and I'm not going to do a full run down.

A quick fix would be to add `display: inline-block` to the css for that div. This will stop it taking a 100% width.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I have that div on my to redo list so hopefully I'll be able to make it work better later.